# I can't access the Pushpin.location

Tags: windows-phone, pushpin

I'm working on VisualBasic Windows Phone Application. I was trying to add pushpins on the bing map on my content panel but I can't seem to access the 'Pushpin' class properly. This surely will sound so noob but I just started learning last 2 days. I'm very careful to ask in here and researched it well but I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.

My xaml.vb header looks like this

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Shell
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports System.Windows.Controls.Primitives
Imports System.Device.Location
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports Windows.Devices.Geolocation
Imports System.IO.IsolatedStorage
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Maps
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls
Imports Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Toolkit
```

And the pivot item, the map tag is incorporated here

```
            <Grid Margin="0,0,10,0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="0*"/>      
                <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <maps:Map x:Name="myMap" Margin="0,0,10,10" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,37,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Latitude:" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="76"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,59,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Longitude:" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.646,1.019" Height="27" Width="94"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="lat_dbl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,37,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Lat_double" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="97"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="long_dbl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="124,59,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="long_double" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="110"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Status" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Location Service Status" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,5,233,0" Grid.Row="1" Height="27" Width="203"/>
                <Slider x:Name="pitchSlider_pitch" ValueChanged="sliderChanged_pitch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="342.844,210.275,-87.156,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190.312" Height="165.45" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Slider.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="-89.579"/>
                    </Slider.RenderTransform>
                </Slider>
                <Slider x:Name="pitchSlider_zoom" ValueChanged="sliderChanged_zoom" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244.844,-37.725,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190.312" Height="165.45" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Slider.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform Rotation="0.598"/>
                    </Slider.RenderTransform>
                </Slider>

            </Grid>

        </phone:PivotItem>
```

Comment: I'm also very new with windows phone development. I didn't check the whole tags but You might change content of design accidentaly. Maybe you can try to undo changes or add another screen to your project? (a)

Comment: I tried it in a new project. I can't really seem to work it out. I could call the pushpin class and generate the imports namespace above but the 'location' property of it is not appearing in the intellisense.

Comment: I wish i knew the answer but i don't know. As for the code, you probably know it's simple:
    GeoCoordinate myLocation = new GeoCoordinate(39.8666, 32.866);
    Pushpin pin1 = new Pushpin();
    pin1.Location = myLocation;

But i never had that kind of problem within that small amount of studying :/